# How to stub the connection property (NEVPNConnection) in NEVPNManager?

Tags: swift, nevpnmanager

I would like to extend the existing `NetworkExtension` classes by a protocol, in order to unit test my code.

I have first created the protocol for `NEVPNManager`

```
protocol NEVPNManagerProtocol {
    var connection : ConnectionProtocol { get } // <-- Doesn't work
    func loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Swift.Void)
    func saveToPreferences(completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Swift.Void)?)
}

extension NEVPNManager: NEVPNManagerProtocol {}
```

And then the separate protocol for `connection` property to stub it out.

```
protocol ConnectionProtocol {
    var status: NEVPNStatus { get }
    func stopVPNTunnel()
    func startVPNTunnel() throws
}

extension NEVPNConnection : ConnectionProtocol {}
```

Inside NEVPNManager I can see that I'm confirming to the property signature, and yet Xcode doesn't believe me and claims that:

> Type 'NEVPNManager' does not conform to protocol
>   'NEVPNManagerProtocol'

And it tries to autocorrect it like this:

```
extension NEVPNManager: NEVPNManagerProtocol {
    var connection: ConnectionProtocol {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

But checking the signature in `NEVPNManager`, it seems correct to me:

```
     /*!
     * @property connection
     * @discussion The NEVPNConnection object used for controlling the VPN tunnel.
     */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    open var connection: NEVPNConnection { get }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocking this is tricky because Apple controls the instantiation of the `NEVPNManager` and its `NEVPNConnection`.

The error you're seeing is because you are trying to redefine the `connection` property, and you can't do that. `NEVPNManager` already has a `connection` property of type `NEVPNConnection`.

We can mock the `connection` property using a combination of your first protocol (modified) and a couple mock classes.

First, the protocol needed to be tweaked slightly:

```
protocol NEVPNManagerProtocol {
    var connection : NEVPNConnection { get } // <-- has to be this type
    func loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Swift.Void)
    func saveToPreferences(completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Swift.Void)?)
}

extension NEVPNManager: NEVPNManagerProtocol {}
```

Next, we need a mock connection *class*, since the `connection` property must be a class of type `NEVPNConnection`, or one inheriting from that type. There doesn't seem to be much benefit to introducing a protocol here, since we are trying to mock the behavior of the class, which we can do more directly with a mock.

```
class MockNEVPNConnection: NEVPNConnection {
    override var status: NEVPNStatus {
        return NEVPNStatus.connected //or whatever
    }
    override func stopVPNTunnel() {
        print("MockNEVPNConnection.stopVPNTunnel")
    }
    override func startVPNTunnel() throws {
        print("MockNEVPNConnection.startVPNTunnel")
    }
 }
```

Finally, we need a mock manager class that returns a mock connection. Using a mock manager was the only way I was able to inject a mock connection.

The mock manager conforms to the `NEVPNManagerProtocol` and returns our mock connection object. (Note: When trying to inherit directly from `NEVPNManager`, my playground crashed on instantiating the mock.)

```
class MockNEVPNManager: NEVPNManagerProtocol {
    var connection: NEVPNConnection {
        return MockNEVPNConnection()
    }
    func loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
        print("MockNEVPNManager.loadFromPreferences")
    }
    func saveToPreferences(completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Swift.Void)?) {
        print("MockNEVPNManager.saveToPreferences")
    }
}
```

The client class must take an object of type `NEVPNManagerProtocol` and not `NEVPNManager`, so that we can pass the mock to it.

```
class MyClient {
    let manager: NEVPNManagerProtocol
    init(manager: NEVPNManagerProtocol) {
        self.manager = manager
    }
}
```

In real life, we can pass the real manager to our client:

```
let myClient = MyClient(manager: NEVPNManager.shared())
```

In our test, we can pass the mock:

```
let myMockedClient = MyClient(manager: MockNEVPNManager())
```

And call methods on the connection:

```
try? myMockedClient.manager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
//prints "MockNEVPNConnection.startVPNTunnel"
```

Comment: That was amazing! Thank you. I have tried to create Mocks by subclassing it last night, and I got the same exception thrown as you had.  It didn't occur to me to use a combination of protocols and mock objects.  Now I learnt how mock system classes. :-) Cheers!